# How to retrieve values related to a hash key present in a Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to retrieve values related to a hash key present in a `Array` of `Hash`es. That is, I have the following `Array` of `Hash`es:

```
[
  {
    :key1 => value_a_1,
    :key2 => value_a_2
  },
  {
    :key1 => value_b_1,
    :key2 => value_b_2
  },
  {
    :key1 => value_c_1,
    :key2 => value_c_2
  }
]
```

I would like to "retrieve" / "build" the following:

```
[ value_a_1, value_b_1, value_c_1 ]
```

How can I make that the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is the array:

```
a.map { |i| i[:key1] }
```